# how to update global config(username and useremail) in git?

Tags: git, git-config

I don't know if i can ask this kind of question here, if can't, sorry.

in a git repository, i use global username `Aname`, and global usermail `aemail@email.com`, and submitted some works to this repository, and now I update my global username to `Bname`, and global usermail to `bemail@email.com` and also submitted some works to this repository. so how can i update global config in old works, please look at picture.
[image]

thanks.

Comment: You can't, not without rewriting the history anyway.

Comment: You're gonna have to amend all commits with the --author flag

Comment: @TimCastelijns what's the command? git commit --amend --author? but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) chapter of [The Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/) has the information you're look for, specifically under "Changing E-Mail Addresses Globally".

If you are using your repository only for personal development, this is fine, but if you are sharing this repository with other people rewriting history like this is an intrusive change.  You cannot actually *modify* an existing commit, so what happens in a situation like this is that `git` generates *new* commits and discards the old ones.  This can be inconvenient if (for example) someone has created a branch off one of the old commits.